# Getting Debian make-kpkg to build a custom kernel for 586 processors

Tags: debian, linux-kernel

I am attempting to build a custom kernel for the i386 architecture and I have been trying to target the kernel at the 586 processor.

I have a kernel configuration, which defines `CONFIG_M586=y`, in the kernel source tree:
./arch/x86/configs/i386_vyos_defconfig

I then run `make i386_vyos_defconfig` followed by `make-kpkg kernel_image`.
However at some point during the build process the `.config` file is updated to set `CONFIG_M686=y` instead.

I have attempted to set '--subarch i586' but it doesn't seem to help.

What is going on and how I configure it to target 586 instead, or not update the `.config` file?

My Kernel configuration is here:
https://gist.github.com/njh/d6191ee130620ccd190e9273864775bd

I am using kernel-package version 13.014+nmu1 on Debian 8 (jessie).

Comment: If you are doing it because you need CPU support, have a look at Antix

Comment: I am going to it add i386 support to VyOS 1.2.0 (which is based on Debian Jessie)

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked out how to fix it but I am now confident that my issue is a bug, not a feature of Debian kernel building.

I traced the kernel change back to the following chain of events:

1. Run: `make-kpkg kernel_image`
2. This executes `make -f /usr/share/kernel-package/ruleset/minimal.mk debian`
3. Which ends uo triggering the target: `debian/stamp/pre-build-common`
4. Which depends on the target: `debian/stamp/conf/vars`
5. Which executes: `make -f ./debian/ruleset/kernel_version.mk debian_conf_var`
6. `kernel_version.mk` includes the main Linux kernel Makefile
7. For some reason this causes the Linux Makefile to run `make syncconfig` - I don't think it is supposed to

As far as I understand from reading [an article about Kconfig/kbuild](https://opensource.com/article/18/10/kbuild-and-kconfig), the `syncconfig` target is just supposed to take the current configuration and generate some derived files from it. But for some reason it is changing my .config file too.

I think I have been far enough down this rabbit hole - time to escape.

Comment: See also: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=890817